# Application Files and Folders cleanup when Uninstalling the App

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that allows exporting files to a non-standard folder on the device's file system.

I put the exports in a folder separate from the application data, because I want the user to be able to navigate to the files using a file-system explorer, and the application data folders/files are not accessible that way.

However, when the application is uninstalled, those non-application-data folders, the folders separate from the application-data file structure, are left behind.

Is there anyway to call an uninstall script, and if so, how is the script called/executed when uninstalling through Android Market or through the device's uninstall in the settings for 'Manage Applications'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE)

I believe this should work for you. Unfortunately, it's for API 14. I don't know it that falls into your needs.

Comment: My app needs to support API 8 and above so far, because the device I use it on is Android 2.3.

Comment: But thank you for the answer, it looks like for API 14 apps, now we can create a custom uninstaller either as part of the app or a separate uninstaller app.